# Google calendar API - How to make a request without having to prompt a login?

Tags: google-api

I have a simple question:

I am developing a website that needs full authorisation to make requests to a Google calendar. I manage to do all the requests I need with javascript from a web server and it works, but I need to be logged into my google account for it to work. This caused a problem for other users that use my website because the request doesn't work if they are not logged into **MY** google account.

I understand why it doesn't work, my question is How can I do for my website to get full access granted for use the google calendar without having to log into my google account, even better if nobody had to log into a Google account to perform the task??

Answer (score 0):

The form of login you are currently using is called Oauth2.  It requires that a user authenticate access.

What you should be using is a service account.  Service accounts are pre authorized.  You will need to share your personal calendar with the service account then it will be able to access it.

The only drawback is that service account authentication is not supported by JavaScript you will need to switch to a server sided language like node.js for example.

```
'use strict';

const {google} = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path');

/**
 * The JWT authorization is ideal for performing server-to-server
 * communication without asking for user consent.
 *
 * Suggested reading for Admin SDK users using service accounts:
 * https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation
 *
 * See the defaultauth.js sample for an alternate way of fetching compute credentials.
 */
async function runSample () {
  // Create a new JWT client using the key file downloaded from the Google Developer Console
  const client = await google.auth.getClient({
    keyFile: path.join(__dirname, 'jwt.keys.json'),
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
  });

  // Obtain a new drive client, making sure you pass along the auth client
  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v2',
    auth: client
  });

  // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
  const res = await drive.files.list();
  console.log(res.data);

  return res.data;
}

if (module === require.main) {
  runSample().catch(console.error);
}

// Exports for unit testing purposes
module.exports = { runSample };
```

Code ripped from smaples [jwt](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/jwt.js)